# Medoo SQL IN or similar functionalty

Tags: php, sql, medoo

I have a `Type` column in my database, which contains the entity type, from a set of defined strings. How can I make a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM "Table" WHERE "Type" IN ('a','b','c');
```

The `IN` condition doesn't seem to be supported by Medoo, and even a `WHERE` condition like

```
'OR' => [
    'Type' => 'a',
    'Type' => 'b',
    'Type' => 'c',
]
```

will not work for the duplicated keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IN` is supported by Medoo & is used like this:

```
$database->select("table", "*", [
    "type" => ['a', 'b', 'c']
  ]
);

// Its equivalent to : ...WHERE "type" IN ('a','b','c') ...
```